# SpaceX Falcon 9 Heavy Launch 4/11/19

Tags: rockets, tracking

Will it be possible to see the launch from the Dominican Republic as to goes into space?  Staying there the next few days/nights.

What is the track out of Cape Canaveral?

[image: Florida and the Dominican Republic]

Comment: Oh, *that's* where [Turks and Caicos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turks_%26_Caicos_(film)) is!